# how to display full SQL query run by entity framework LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Say I have a LINQ query:

```
var query = (from person in ctx.People where person.Name == "John" select person);
```

`ctx` is a context inheriting from `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`.

Now how do I get the full SQL query including the parameters? I have tried:

```
var sql = ((ObjectQuery) query).ToTraceString();
sql = query.String();
context.Database.Log = (s) => sql += s;
```

The first solution throws an invalid cast exception.
The second solution gives me only the query part which references variables that are not included.
The third prints the "variables" in a strange format.

Comment: Did you tried LINQPad ? http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: is the query correct copy/pasted or just typed? "where person.Name = "John" " is doing an assignment instead of an equality test.

Comment: @user1666620 Just a random typed query, fixed that error now

Comment: @user1151923 Which version of EF are you using? The method varies... e.g. ToTraceString will not work as simply as you are using it if you are using EF6

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I view the SQL generated by the entity framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

`var query = from person in ctx.People where person.Name == "John" select person;
 string Sql = ctx.GetCommand(query).CommandText;`

Comment: The `DbContext` class does not contain the GetCommand method.